# Edittext change width with animation

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-animation

I want to make an edittext which aligns in its parent's left and when users click it, edittext's width'll increase to right side. Here is the code that i used. But when animation ended, edittext width come to first size.
Can any one help me.?
And is there any solution to set "fillparent" to width's final size in animation?

```
Animation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0, -500, 1, 1);
scaleAnimation.setDuration(750);
editText.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

I added `scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);` before animation starts but i get this;
[image]

After 750ms, edittext is going to its first width.

Comment: See the edit in my answer, or refer to [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)

Comment: Please qualify your "try ObjectAnimator". Pointing people to other APIs and frameworks with no indication of why or even if it will work is not helpful for others trying to find the same solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This will definitely work for you.**

> Dynamic way of doing this:

```
ScaleAnimation animate = new ScaleAnimation(1, 2, 1, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);
animate.setDuration(700);
animate.setFillAfter(true);
target.startAnimation(animate);
```

> Way of Using XML

**scale.xml** (Put this in res/anim folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:fillAfter="true"        
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toXScale="2.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

**Java Code:**

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Anims.this, R.anim.scale);
mEdittext.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: can you share the code of edittext how it's look like pleasd

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
Animation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0, -500, 1, 1);
    scaleAnimation.setDuration(750);
    scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    editText.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
```

Or use ObjectAnimator:

```
ObjectAnimator animWidth = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(your_view, "width", startWidth,endWith);
animWidth.setDuration(yourDuration);
animWidth.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to this one.

Animation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0, -500, 1, 1);

```
         scaleAnimation.setDuration(750);

        scaleAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                          //Set your editext width to match parent using layout params
                        }
                    });
        editText.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

Comment: Posting code with no explanation of WHY he should try it or even any explanation of how you think this works is neither helpful nor constructive not a good use of SO. Please please add some text explaining WHY he should try this one.

Comment: Every answer in this post is of same kind with no comments or explanation, but yes explanation is required.