# How do I make a shape scale up and stay that size in android?

Tags: android, xml

I have some knowledge of drawables and animations in android. I created a drawable rectangle along with an animation scale. Here is my scale.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="2.0" />

</set>
```

Here is my rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#5a5a5a88"
                    android:endColor="#14141488"
                    android:angle="270" android:centerX="0.25"/>

       </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

When I launch the app and click on the rectangle, it just grows and then goes back to it's regular scale. I want it to grow and stay that scale. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
android:fillAfter="true"
```

to make your view stable at the end of the animation. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552429/edittext-change-width-with-animation/21555439#21555439)